# How to execute code when a new window opens in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I want the code in `execute()` to be executed when the window the controller belongs to is opened. How would I do so?

```
public class OpenAccountScreenController {
    public TableView openAccountTableView = new TableView();
    public TableColumn accountNameColumn = new TableColumn();
    public TableColumn accountNumberColumn = new TableColumn();

    public void execute() {
        accountNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("accountName"));
        accountNumberColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("accountNumber"));

        for(Account account : accounts.values()) {
            openAccountTableView.getItems().add(account);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly that you want to call `execute()` in another class once the Window/Stage is shown, so you can do something like this:

```
OpenAccountScreenController obj = new OpenAccountScreenController();

stage.setOnShowing(e-> obj.execute());
```

Otherwise please clarify.

Comment: No, I want to call/execute the code within the OpenAccountScreenController to populate the table with values once the window is opened. @Yahya

Comment: @SergeyGrinev That won't work because we are creating a new instance of OpenAccountScreenController. I need a way to populate the table without creating a new instance of the controller.

Comment: so use it in the `initialize()`, get any node call `getScene()` and use it.